# Phpseclib timeout for read()

Tags: php, debian, phpseclib, mod-fcgid, fcgid

I'm using https://github.com/phpseclib/phpseclib to execute cmd's on a Debian server.

```
echo $ssh->exec("ls");
```

is working fine for me - but if i try the following (like [here](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/ssh/examples.html#interactive,logging)) a timeout appears:

```
$ssh->write("ls -la\n");

echo $ssh->read();
```

Error log say:

```
[warn] mod_fcgid: read data timeout in 10 seconds 
[error] Premature end of script headers: index.php
```

i also tried to increase fcgid settings (up to 300s):

```
FcgidBusyTimeout 10
FcgidIOTimeout 10
```

Doesn't works ... any help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You normally need to do `$ssh->read('[prompt]')` where [prompt] is a placeholder for the actual prompt. If you don't know the prompt or need to figure it out you can do `$ssh->setTimeout(3)` before the `$ssh->read()`.